# dynamic shortened text areas with "See more" link

Tags: jquery, drupal, drupal-6, textarea

I need to add text areas to my website with the following charateristics:

- Only the first 2 lines should be visible with a "See more" link.
- When the user clicks on see more the remaining text is displayed without page refresh...

It should be similar to Facebook "See more" functionality, showing the complete comments content, if these are shortened.

Optionally I would like to use a sliding effect to show the full content of the text area.

thanks

Comment: I've created a View and added the text area field for each item. I've also trimmed it and add a "See more link..." However I don't want it to redirect to the full node, I want to show the complete text and add a small animation (sliding up) to show it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way I can think of to achieve the effect you're looking for would be to load the full text, but then use something like the [jQuery Expander Plugin](http://plugins.learningjquery.com/expander/index.html) to take care of hiding the "extra" text until a user chooses to click on the link.

Comment: I would also like to do this, but I don't want to arbitrarily chop of dthe text.  I want to do this at a word boundary.  I don't think Expander is up to it.

Comment: ProfK, there are others: http://rockycode.com/blog/jquery-plugin-readmore/ I bet there are more. And it shouldn't be difficult to add word boundary detection.